# P'nei Eretz Yisrael, P'nei Shabbat Kodesh?

Tags: shabbat, eretz-yisrael, bentching, nuschaot

Once I was in the land of Israel (in Beit Shemesh), and the mazmin was leading birkat hamazon.  He said birshut maranan verabanan verabotai, birshut hakohanim, and birshut p'nei eretz yisrael.  Is this common practice in other places in the land?  How about saying birshut p'nei shabbat on shabbes koidesh?

Comment: The mazmin was Ashkenazic, so maybe that is why he said p'nei E"Y.

Comment: Based on the number of places I have seen Birkat HaMazon led in Israel, I would venture to guess that this is not common practice in many places.

Comment: Are you sure it was _p'ne_ and not _b'ne_? Was he a foreigner, who perhaps felt that he needed to beg permission from locals (who he perhaps felt were more deserving of conducting the _zimun_)?

Comment: @msh210 – Now that I think about it, it is certainly possible. IIRC, he made *Aliyya* with his family when he was a child.